# How to make SQL view when table might not have column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Running into an issue where I have to write a sql view in big query where the columns on the table might or might not exist (the table is dynamically created by another system, the view is required to be written by a human). It looks like CROSS APPLY or CROSS JOIN LATERAL might work, but big query doesn't support that. Any way to do this using standard SQL?

EDIT: for example,

```
SELECT x
FROM table
```

where an automated process is adding x to the table at a random point in the future but people are building reports off this view today.

Comment: I would suggest you use a stored procedure to inspect the source table metadata and create the view accordingly. A simple view cannot work with columns that may or not exist.

Comment: If stored procedures aren't an option due to stupid, stupid reasons, any other options?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Based on this (abridged) statement: _I have to write a sql view in big query where the columns on the table might or might not exist. The view is required to be written by a human_ The solution is to find a human that knows how to create a view that excludes columns that don't exist. Can you rewrite your question to make your requirements clearer?

Comment: updated description

Comment: _"must be written by a human"_ - uh, are you unwittingly being used as a control-subject in a machine-learning (LLM?) experiment?

Comment: _"any other options?"_ - With dynamic-SQL, sure - but you can't use dynamic-SQL inside a `VIEW` (and `VIEW` objects _must_ have a fixed, well-defined schema) - so what you're trying to do is literally impossible.

Comment: Push back on the source and *require* column `x` to be present, even if in some cases it contains only null values.